Has any more abstract representation of choropleth data been measured as more impactful than the Mercator world map projection version
Has anyone studied seriously the impact of the shape of the world when conveying data about people on land?
If so, did they compare our Western Mercator projection  with abstract ideas?
We are thinking of two things really: shape - the Mercator projection map is 70% sea, there are cases where the sea may be the focus, but not for this; and recognisability, for example, places where people suffer may be known, home countries can be found. And the Mercator projection centres the land, splitting the Pacific

Or, for an interactive example, check out my site version here. Selecting "WB Internet Use" will give real world data and remember this just a one-person demo, it's a little rough around the edges.
To define impact: the higher the impact the more the researchers' intended data has stood out, without prompting.
To define abstract: eight billion people, a box graphic 4000 by 2000, filled with blocks of different colours. It's not a map, but it can still represent the same data.

I can't speak for the difference between a more abstract or accurate version of map design, there are also similar discussions and analysis of public transport/transit map design (the so-called subway maps). Every time a new design is proposed for the major networks like NY or London there is always intense debate and discussion about its merits.
The fact is, the principle of data visualization design doesn't provide a 'perfect' solution - there are simple different options for the data/information you want to highlight, or the message/story that you want to tell. You can't highlight everything (otherwise it won't stand out), nor can you tell a story from every single possible perspective.
So I guess a map designed for a specific purpose is going to work better most of the time for that specific purpose. A visually accurate map is probably better when you want to know the exact distance and time required to cover that ground (e.g. elevation details, terrain type, etc.), while a more abstract map is going to be more effective at summarizing or condensing details so that they can be recalled more easily. This is consistent with what I know about the evolution of map representation in different fields, as well as the general principles of data visualization design.
